# Exclude redux-form reducer from main store

Tags: redux, store, redux-form

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form'

combineReducers({
 router: connectRouter(history),
 form,
 ....
 // huge amount of other reducers
})
```

Above you can see combined `reducers` in one `store`. As bigger it becomes as slower it becomes because on each action it should make many more checks as it was at the beginning. As you also can see I use `redux-form` for handling `state` in my form. And it starts to be slower and slower when I type in `redux-form` fields. I want to find out is there any way to create some individual store for `redux-form`, and prevent this from slowing down. Or is there exist some other solutions to this problem?

Comment: How do you know that your performance issues have something to do with redux store size? Have you tried to exclude other reducers temporarily and measure performance?

Answer (score 0):

Using `redux` you can have multiple stores.
`redux-form` is using `connect` API from `react-redux` to get info from store.

> With React Redux, the wrapper classes generated by the connect() function do actually look for props.store if it exists, but it's best if you wrap your root component in  and let React Redux worry about passing the store down. This way components don't need to worry about importing a store module, and isolating a Redux app or enabling server rendering is much easier to do later.
>
> https://redux.js.org/faq/store-setup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself

I'm a `redux-form` collaborator.